# Is it supposed to take 35 seconds everytime I launch an android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to learn to develop Android apps. I followed the steps at http://developer.android.com to get my eclipse environment set up for android. I am able to launch android apps and the emulator comes up and loads the app.

It is taking over 30 seconds every time though. I thought it was supposed to take a while the first time but be fine after that. Is this normal?

When it first loads 2-3 command prompt boxes appear and disappear very quickly. Then it says "A N D R O I D _" with the underscore blinking for a while, then is shows the word *android* again but in a fancy font. then the application finally loads.

I am using Win7x64 if it matters.

Comment: That's always been my experience. Know that you don't have to restart the emulator every time you rebuild. Stop the instance of your app before you rebuild and the emulator will just pick up the new instance after you finish.

Comment: its not just the emulator either, devices are slow too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're closing the emulator after each run. If you leave the emulator open the loading time should be reduced as you expected. However, do bear in mind the emulator is generally very slow.

Answer (score 2):

It is not out of the normal for the emulator starting to take a significant amount of time. It's a known issue.

I would suggest that you do not terminate the emulator instance while you are working. A redeploy on a running Android emulator will go faster. Once you are ready to test from scratch go ahead and start a clean instance. This will reduce your sit and wait time significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Android emulator is exceedingly slow to launch, every time, even on a good machine with an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the emulator running in between builds. Start the emulator when you start working on the project, then after your first build/run, leave the emulator running. Click build/run again and it should be much faster since it doesn't have to boot the whole OS again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your PC, before it had to take 15 min before i bought a mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Emulator with low resolution , then it will load in less time . For Ex. if you use HVGA in the place of WVGA800 , the it will load faster . In toolbar , go to window and then click on Android SDK and AVD manager , and then edit your Emulator . Try this out ...